# Task starts with delay

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I create and start task in following way:

```
 Task task = new Task(() => controller.Play());
 task.Start();
```

For some reason, sometimes task get started with around 7-10 seconds delay. 
I use 6 tasks in parallel, max number of tasks is 32767 and available 32759
which is what i log before i create task so it can't be that max number of tasks is reached. I write log at the first line of code in controller.Play() method that task should execute, so there is no lock or anything that could make task to wait.

Comment: how and where do you measure the delay? maybe the `controller.Play` call has a startup cost.

Comment: Sidenote: recommend way to start a task is using `Task.Run()`

Comment: I have adjusted it to use Run() instead of Start() still the same problem. I realized that program deserialize from JSON file that is 10MB large on another Thread, which takes around 10 seconds, and as soon as this is done, tasks which call controller.Play() are started. I tried to delete those lines of code that deserialize from json, then there is no delay at all. I also tried to make controller.Play() empty function, still it is called once deserialize from json is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long running tasks, like your deserialization of 100MB that takes 10 seconds, should be, hm, well, run as [long-running tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2) :-)

Long-running tasks are, as per the current implementation, always run on a dedicated thread and they do not put pressure on the thread-pool.

In your case, you perhaps only two tasks - the deserialization and the player. The TaskScheduler works under the assumption that tasks are short-lived, and in this case, it obviously schedules the "player" task to run after the "deserializaion" one.

Comment: I have few long running tasks, that do some work within short time then sleep for 1 second and again do some work besides reading from 10MB file. Should i put all those long running on background worker?

Comment: The background worker also uses the thread pool.  Put them all on separate threads.

Comment: I did use long running task option, now it works fine, thank you